# I want to create an SRT file quickly, is there any way I can take advantage of how the dialogue is per image?

Tags: video, caption

[I have a channel at YouTube,](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCJv0STX-xSkapow54orIJ6g?view_as=subscriber) if you look at it you'll notice I'm far behind and I have over 200 videos that still don't have captions. So, I want to create captions through SRT files. If you watch one of the video, you'll notice that a new verse starts when an image changes, I want to take advantage of this and find a way to use the start time of a new image to put it to an SRT file. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the actual videos, you can make use of ffmpeg to find the scene changes. You can try the following with some optimum value for scene change threshold (like 40 or 50).

```
ffmpeg -i <input> -vf select='gte(scene,50)',metadata=print:file=scenescores.txt -an -f null -
```

Ref:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40688062/ffmpeg-get-the-scene-change-detection-value-for-all-frame

Comment: I'm an amateur. How can I try the follow code? Where should I write if?